# Logstash 7.10.02 failed to start on windows

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I tried starting the logstash with the below command

```
logstash-7.10.2\logstash -f logstash.conf
```

> logstash.conf

```
input{
    file{
        path => "D://server.log" start_position=> "beginning" type => "logs"
    }
}
filter {
  grok {
        match => {"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime} \[%{NOTSPACE:thread}\] \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\] %{GREEDYDATA:line}"
        }  
    }
}
output {
    if "ERROR" in [loglevel]
    { 
        elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "logstash" 
    }
    }
}
```

command prompt displayed the below text and did not start logstash.

Using JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221;
WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK
warning: ignoring JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64m -Xmx128m -XX:NewSize=64m -XX:MaxNewSize=64m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=64m; pass JVM parameters via LS_JAVA_OPTS

No error logs were created.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried staring logstash in debug mode .

> `--log.level DEBUG`

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline looks okay. Can you try adding below output to see if you the pattern and log data matches. Just to rule out any grokparsefailures.

```
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    if "ERROR" in [loglevel]
    { 
        elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "logstash" 
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that too, still now luck.